# External monitor black when connect magsafe in macbook pro

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, macbook, macbook-pro, mini-displayport

I have a problem with magsafe and miniDisplay Port to connect external monitor.

I connect my macbook pro (mid 2012 with MacOS Sierra) to Dell S2415H with miniDisplay Port to HDMI cable and all its ok if the magsafe is disconnect. But when connect my magsafe, my Dell S2415H turns blank, if disconnect again, my monitor is alive and get image and sound.

I reset my SMC, PRAM , reinstall my SO and trying in safe mode, but nothing help.

Anybody knows it's the problem? or have the same issue?

Comment: Does it do this in safe mode?  Hold `Shift` while booting.

Comment: Yes, I try in safe mode option and get the same, black screen ;/

Comment: The problem is hardware then.  You need to test out with a different monitor and if the problem continues, try a different adapter.  I am not a fan of going from mDP to HDMI.  HDMI is flaky to begin with - your best bet to go mDP to mDP/DP.  Try not to make any conversions if you don't have to.

Comment: Do you think is a problem of my Macbook? because I try with other cables (mDP to HDMI, adapter to mDP to HDMI ...)  but have the same issue. I can't try with mDP to mDP because my monitor not have mDP or DP only VGA and HDMI. The image and sound found in my external monitor if remove my magsafe but when I put again, my monitor go to black and sound is off ;(

Comment: The other thing I would try is to disable "auto brightness" - it's under Displays in System Prefs.  When you plug it in, it may be trying to set the brightness outside the range of the monitor.

Comment: I disabled the "auto brightness" in my System Prefs but when put my magsafe my brightness change automatic even if be disabled and my external monitor go to black screen and the audio is off ;/.